# Why does background-image break my layout?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my background image with a transparent overlay that's split into top and bottom.

Lastnight, in SO Chat, I tried to supply the guys with a JSFiddle, but after posting the code, JSFiddle wasn't able to reproduce the layout correctly. So here's what the desired effect should look like:

(note that this is hand drawn and so you can't see a background image):

[image]

You can see that the page should be split horizontally. The blue part should be 50% high and the white part should be 50% high. With a logo in the centre. However, when I add the background image, the white section is pushed down, like this:

(note you still can't see a background image, because it's hand drawn):

[image]

Adding a background image to the `html` element, `body` element *or* any child container causes the white div to either be cut off at its top or pushed down, leaving a *gap* between the bottom edge of the blue section and the top edge of the white section.

How can I get my background image to *stop* affecting the flow of the document? I didn't think that CSS background images affected layout?

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <title>Home | Hmmm</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Shared/Assets/Stylesheets/Core.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Shared/Assets/Stylesheets/Home.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img id="key" src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/Icons/Kdfg.png" alt="Sign In | Create an Account" />
            <img id="logo" src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/Logos/JdfgWLSS.png" alt="Hmmm" />
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            <footer>
                <p style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; color: white;">&copy; Hmmm 2015</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    border: 0;

    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/JWSSB.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;

    background-color: #2695D7;

    opacity: 0.8;
}

#main
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#key
{
    float: right;
}

#logo
{
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0 auto;

    position: absolute;
    right: calc(100% / 2 - 176px / 2);
    bottom: calc(100% / 2 - 100px / 2);
}

#sections
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.section
{
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a workaround. I don't understand it, but it's alright *for now*:

Add a border to the top of the white section:

```
#main
{
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;

    border-top: 0.1px solid white;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Then, make the logo appear on top again by changing its z-index:

```
#logo
{
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0 auto;

    position: absolute;
    right: calc(100% / 2 - 176px / 2);
    bottom: calc(100% / 2 - 100px / 2);

    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to:

```
body {

    height: 100vh
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(...image...);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#main
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I _did_ tell you that and I even _showed_ you that. And a single image would NOT solve this problem because then I'd still need the two containers and they would still be broken.

Comment: _"I have a certain effect that I am trying to achieve and I have done it but part of that effect requires a background image"_ << Doesn't really help. Is there a reason you've specified your body CSS twice? Could you please confirm the desired effect is "To have a transparent overlay placed over a background image, which is split horizontally at 50%"

Comment: Because I don't want to apply the background image to BOTH the html and body elements.

Comment: I have already tried having just one body, doesn't affect the outcome though, it still pushes the white section down.

Comment: ????? The body element spans the entire doc, if you put an image in it, it's going to cover the entire doc. I'm not sure why you're trying to target the html element in your CSS but that does nothing

Comment: Regardless, it's completely irrelevant to the problem. Thanks for tyring to help though. :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes required. You should go through your CSS and strip out what you don't need though, it's messy and will cause problems, mainly confusing you when you're setting properties in more than one place, you're going to run into specificity issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this way will be okay for you, but still. [Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tf2vxtf/)

html:

```
<div class='top'></div>
<img src='http://silvercreekart.weebly.com/uploads/3/7/3/0/37300503/9869404.png' class='logo'/>
<div class='bottom'></div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.top {
    background: cyan;
    height: 50%;
}
.bottom {
    background: grey;
    height: 50%;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -128px 0 0 -128px;
}
```

I like my way much more then using calc. It is better way if you know sizes of your logo (to put it in the middle with negative margin)